# Why is the constant in differential equations set to c?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Might have been raised and answered a thousand times, but for example in this ODE:

$\begin{align}
&x\,y = y' \\
&\frac{1}{2}\,x^2 + C_1 = \ln(y) + C_2
\end{align}$

I agree at putting $C_1$ and $C_2$ together. But when I'd resolve it for y:

$\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2}\,x^2 + C = \ln(y) \quad|\cdot e^{(\bullet)} \\
&e^{\frac{1}{2}\,x^2} \, e^{C} = y 
\end{align}$

I'd get back $e^{C}$ (in case I'm not totally foolish). However in solutions I always see $C$.

I'd take it if $C$ would stand for $e^{C}$ but in problems with starting conditions involved this is not the case. It really just is a constant. So where am I getting wrong?

Comment: $e^C$ also "really just is a constant" (which you happen to know is positive, but that's beside the point here).

Comment: When I taught an introduction to differential equations, I would use different letters, since students would have the same question you have. But the more proficient you become, the easier it is to think "a constant, whatever it is" instead of the constant $C_1$ or $C_2$ or $D$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this:

$$
xy = y' \\
\frac{1}{2}x^2 + C_1 = \ln(y) + C_2$$

get this:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\,x^2 + K &= \ln(y) \quad \mid e^{(\bullet)} \\
e^{\frac{1}{2}\,x^2} \, e^K &= y 
\end{align}$$

... calling it $K$ rather than $C$.

Then note that if $K$ is an arbitrary constant, then so is $e^K$ -- with the proviso that $e^K > 0$.

So make $C = e^K$.

So you can now say the solution is:

$$y = C e^{\frac{1}{2}\,x^2}$$

taking into account that $C > 0$.

Comment: And if you use that in general $\int\frac{dy}{y}=\ln|y|+C_2$, then you get also the negative sign in $C$. And then also take the zero solution that you hopefully noted as a separate case before dividing by $y$, and also $C=0$ is a valid choice.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Why not add that as a separate answer? That is if you want to spoon-feed everything to OP. I was deliberately only answering what OP asked, leaving it up to him to finish the job.